Receiving Kiss of Deaths with chrony
basically I think the issue is that my company NTP server has a Stratum of 5 and it might be laggy at times - but it's maintained by other team so I don't have much info about it.
Now I have tested multiple pooling times - I also must be wary as we had issues with clock skew before which causes other services to error.
Currently my settings are:
server MY_NTP_SERVER iburst prefer

server 0.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 10 maxpoll 12
server 1.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 10 maxpoll 12
server 2.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 10 maxpoll 12
server 3.pool.ntp.org iburst minpoll 10 maxpoll 12

maxdistance 5.0

stratumweight 0.001 

So the minpool is higher than the recommended/default one and I still receive KoD's from various public NTP servers.
Would appreciate suggestions in topics:

should I care about the KoD's errors at all (as far as I know I should hence the question)

If I force chrony to use only my corp I risk having clock skews when my NTP server lags - also I use the prefer flag so log indicates that I am starting from my company NTP but then it gets switched - sometimes after few minutes, sometimes after hours

maybe I should further increase pooling? Why am I even recieving the KoD's here? Maybe it's the amount of kubernetes nodes that pool the public NTPs (logs indicate that I use various servers so not sure how many at times are pooling for the same IP)


Last solution I was thinking about is configuring my own NTP server and then using my nodes to sync with it - but not sure how much of a hassle that will be I have a very high number of nodes so I don't know if the maintenance will not overcome the advantages of this solution.
Anything else I miss in this picture?

In general when your corporate network has internal NTP servers the internal security guidelines and policies also mandate that you use those exclusively (and prohibit the use of online / internet time servers) -  If the internal ntp solution is unreliable or overloaded ; that is the issue that needs fixing. - Depending on how large a number your ”very high number of nodes” really is , the NTP pool project also may not be suitable for your business requirements. - Running your own internal NTP server can be quite easy , setting it up with an GPS antenna slightly more complicated.

You might find that the KoDs are from your corporate firewalls preventing outbound NTP.  I'd suggest using pool rather than server on the config lines and not trying to constrain the poll times or mark any server as preferred - just let chrony pick the best sources.  If you leave your setup running for a couple of hours then add the output of chronyc -n sources and chronyc -n tracking to your question we might get some better clues.
